# Find the function satisfying these constraints

Tags: calculus

From Stewart's Caclulus 6e

> If $f$ is a differentiable function such that $f(x)$ is never 0 and $\int_0^x f(t) \, dt = \left[ f(x) \right]^2$ for all $x$, find $f$.

My attempt is as follows:

Differentiate both sides and apply the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$ f(x) = 2f(x) f'(x) $$

Since $f$ is never 0 for any $x$

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} \implies f(x) = \dfrac{x}{2} + C$$

How can I determine what $C$ is?  I'm inclined to say $f(0) = 0$ since $\int_0^0 f(t) \, dt = 0 = \left[ f(0) \right]^2$ but that would violate the assumption that $f(x) \neq 0 \forall x$.

Plugging in $f$ to the integral yields

$$ \dfrac{x^2}{4} + Cx = \dfrac{x^2}{4} + Cx + C^2 $$

seemingly also implying $C=0$, but that means $f(0)=0$ again violating the initial assumption.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1392520/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are spot on.  The integral from $0$ to $0$ of any function is $0$, so if the first equation is correct for all $x$ you have $f(x)=0$.  The problem would be better stated that $f(x)\neq 0$ except when $x=0$.  You would then have to make a special argument to show $f(0)=0$ but you have that already.

Answer (score 1):

Either there is a typo in the book, they should have written something like $f(x)\neq 0$ for $x\neq 0$.

But if the problem is correctly written as it is, then you just showed that there exists no such function. In that case, we don't even need to differentiate and solve. We can just put in $x=0$ and show that $f(0)=0$, and hence no such function exists.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)